# Excel: How to find cell in a column that contains a string and return value of a cell in another column of row?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Python with Excel: If a cell in a column contains string, return cell value three cells over to the right.

Trying to come up with a Python script to:

1. look through an excel workbook
2. look through a specified column
3. if the column contains a string, i.e. 'daily sales'
4. return the cell value three columns over

i.e.: If Column E contains 'string' at E25, return the cell value in H25.

I tried the following in python with excel file living in the same directory as my python file:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example-workbook.xlsx')
sheet = wb.activelist(sheet.columns)[1]

for cellObj in list(sheet.columns)[4]:
    print(cellObj.value)
```

Column E corresponds with column 4.

I'm able to return all values in Column E using the above.

Comment: @martineau sorry about that and thanks for pointing that out. first time using this site. I've added what I've attempted already to the original post

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very literal implementation of the steps outlined in your question. It makes use of the worksheet [`iter_cols()`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_cols) method to iterate through the target column values looking for the target string and when if finds it—assuming it does—it uses the `offset()` cell method to access the desired cell value. Otherwise it raises an exception. The methods of the `Cell` class are in the `openpyxl.cell.cell` module and documented [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html#module-openpyxl.cell.cell). Kudos to @Charlie Clark for pointing it out to me.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.cell import column_index_from_string

class NotFoundError(LookupError):
    ''' Exception raised if target string isn't found. '''
    def __init__(self, target_string, column, excel_filepath):
        self.target_string = target_string
        message = (f'{target_string!r} target string not found in column '
                   f'{column!r} of Excel file {excel_filepath!r}')
        super().__init__(message)


def get_offset_column(excel_filepath, column, target_string, offset):
    ''' Search column of specified workbook for target string and return value of
        cell offset a given number of columns from that one.
    '''
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_filepath)
    ws = wb.active
    column_index = column_index_from_string(column)

    # Look through the cells of the specified column.
    # If a cell contains target string, return value of the cell at offset column.
    cells = next(ws.iter_cols(min_col=column_index, max_col=column_index)) # Only one col.
    for cell in cells:
        if cell.value == target_string:
            return cell.offset(column=offset).value
    else:
        raise NotFoundError(target_string, column, excel_filepath)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = get_offset_column('example-workbook.xlsx', 'E', 'daily sales', 3)
    print(result)  # -> 42
```

The printed result shown was from running it on the following `example-workbook.xlsx` file I created for testing purposes:

[image: screenshot of excel file]

Comment: Why is this so verbose and using column letter lookups?

Comment: @Charlie: Because A). I an showing the OP the basics of how to do what they want, not produce highly optimized code, and B). I am certainly not any kind of `openpyxl` expert and wrote my answer relying primarily on its documentation.

Comment: thank you @martineau I really need to improve how I try to tackle a problem and your answer has helped me quite a bit.

Comment: `cell.offset(column=3)`

Comment: Thanks @Charlie. I find the layout/structure of `openpyxl`'s document less-than-useful in the sense that there's no (obvious to me) section defining each of its classes and their methods, as I am accustomed to haveing. This makes it difficult to familiarize oneself with what available.

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html

Comment: @Charlie: I know — I eventually found it and put a link to it in my updated answer.